# When I was doing the leetcode problem, I found it overflowed after typing the code

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, overflow

When I was doing the leetcode problem, I found it overflowed after typing the code. Here is the code
I think it's malloc creating the pointer, but I don't know why it's wrong,

I think the details are enough, why need the details
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

```c
char * longestCommonPrefix(char ** strs, int strsSize){
    int i = 0;
    int p = 0;
    char flag;
    char *str = (char*)malloc(200);
    while(1){
        flag = strs[i][p];
        for(;i<strsSize;i++)
        {
            if(strs[i][p] != flag || strs[i][p] == '\0'){
                strncpy(str,strs[0],p);
                return str;
            }
        }
        p++;
        i=0;
    }
    return str;
}
```

This is an error message

```
=================================================================
==28==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x611000000108 at pc 0x55578ee68187 bp 0x7fff10f58390 sp 0x7fff10f58380
READ of size 1 at 0x611000000108 thread T0
    #0 0x55578ee68186 in __jsonstrserialize__ /leetcode/__SerializerHelper__.inl:94
    #1 0x55578ee6c365 in _serialize_string /leetcode/__Serializer__.c:272
    #2 0x55578ee672e5 in main /leetcode/user_code/prog_joined.c:54
    #3 0x7f069515b0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
    #4 0x55578ee629ad in _start (/leetcode/user_code/prog+0x3d9ad)

0x611000000108 is located 0 bytes to the right of 200-byte region [0x611000000040,0x611000000108)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f0695da0bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #1 0x55578ee66a51 in longestCommonPrefix /leetcode/user_code/prog_joined.c:8
    #2 0x55578ee672cf in main /leetcode/user_code/prog_joined.c:52
    #3 0x7f069515b0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow /leetcode/__SerializerHelper__.inl:94 in __jsonstrserialize__
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c227fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c227fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c227fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c227fff8000: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c227fff8010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c227fff8020: 00[fa]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff8070: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==28==ABORTING
```

Comment: What does "it overflowed" mean? Please describe the original task being solved, provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: `strncpy(str,strs[0],p);` Note that `str` is likely not NUL terminated after that call. From the [strncpy manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy): "**Warning**: *If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.*"

Comment: After debugging the breakpoint, I found that the whole function was executed without any error. After returning STR, the LeetCode compiler reported an error

Comment: See my second comment. The returned `str` is likely not a valid NUL terminated C string.

Comment: Here are descriptions and examplesWrite a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

 

Example 1:

Input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"

Comment: Also, the last `return str;` is returning unintialised memory.

Comment: So how should I fix it

Comment: Please do not put the description in comments. It needs to be in the post.

Comment: `str[p] = 0;` after `strncpy` and `str[0] = 0;` before the last `return str;`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I know how to solve this kind of problem

Comment: Also, note that your code will result in memory corruption if the test code uses input that requires a return string longer than 199 characters.

Comment: I see, but they specify that the length should not be greater than 200, and also, to save memory space, I put malloc inside the if, and the size is p+1,